# Using XSL transformation for XML to HTML conversion

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have written an XSL file for displaying an XML file in HTML tabular format, but it's not working. It's only showing the headers, i.e. `uri` and `literal`. Kindly go through my code and reply to me with solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Query</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
          <THEAD>
            <TR>
              <TD width="35%">
                <B>URI</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="15%">
                <B>Literal</B>
              </TD>
            </TR>
          </THEAD>
          <TBODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="sparql/results/result">
              <TR>
                <TD width="35%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="uri" />
                </TD>
                <TD width="15%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="literal" />
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </TBODY>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="c1"/>
    <variable name="callret-1"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="c1">
        <uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/SVIST</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="callret-1">
        <literal>
          Swami Vivekananda &lt;b&gt;Institute&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;of&lt;/b&gt; Science and      &lt;b&gt;Technology&lt;/b&gt;, a non profit making trust has been set up to... the technological and professional institution &lt;b&gt;of&lt;/b&gt; high standards and to encourage research and... In this era &lt;b&gt;of&lt;/b&gt; economic...
        </literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="c1">
        <uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Haldia_Institute_of_Technology</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="callret-1">
        <literal>
          &lt;b&gt;Haldia&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;Institute&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;of&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;Technology&lt;/b&gt;.
        </literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use XML Namespaces in your stylesheet to match your input document.

Your input document uses a default namespace of

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#
```

Selectors that do not explicitly reference this namespace (with a prefix) *will not work*.

You need to add a namespace to your stylesheet like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:spa="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
```

(Note that you can use whatever prefix you want.)

Then modify your XPath selectors to use this prefix:

```
<xsl:for-each select="spa:sparql/spa:results/spa:result">
    <TR>    
       <TD width="35%"><xsl:value-of select="spa:uri" /></TD>   
       <TD width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="spa:literal" /></TD> 
    </TR>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Also, use indentation and note that HTML elements are lowercase.

Comment: @user2257125, I am going to help by giving you some tips about stackoverflow: (1) Show more effort.  If you made any attempt to solve the problem, include this in your post.  (2) Give more detail.  Don't just say "it's not working."  Say exactly what you expected, and exactly what you got.  (3) Don't post blocks of code in comments.  Consider whether you would deal with someone else's code looking like that.  If you've changed your code, use the "edit" link below your question to update it.

Comment: sorry for that blunder. And i am very thankful to you. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Harpo was right, you just need to include namespace within your XSLT and change your XPATH accordingly. I have done this for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:sq="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Query</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
          <THEAD>
            <TR>
              <TD width="35%">
                <B>URI</B>
              </TD>
              <TD width="15%">
                <B>Literal</B>
              </TD>
            </TR>
          </THEAD>
          <TBODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="sq:sparql/sq:results/sq:result">
              <TR>
                <TD width="35%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="sq:binding/sq:uri" />
                </TD>
                <TD width="15%">
                  <xsl:value-of select="sq:binding/sq:literal" />
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </TBODY>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you sir for your support. that worked. can you help me regarding <b> tags in xml. when i view my xml file in html table format it can not detect <b> tags.